# Wireless Sustain Pedal?

Tags: electronics, equipment

Not sure if this is the appropriate place to ask this question but I don't actually know where I should so I'll ask here anyways. So if someone could point me in the right direction before closing this post or something, that'd be appreciated.

I want a wireless sustain pedal for keyboards... Haven't been able to find them or any indication then exist on the internet lol.

So I was wondering if anybody could take me through a process of what it would take to make one.

I have a feeling this has more to do with circuitry than music, but yk.

[image: sustain pedal]

So I was basically wondering what the process would be like to covert one of these box pedals to a wireless device.

Obviously it needs a dongle... those technically exist already

[image: tattoo pedal dongle]

The picture is of a dongle "pedal plug" for wireless tattoo foot pedals, which operates somewhat like a cross between a guitar expression pedal and a keyboard sustain pedal.

Anyways, what would it take to use these two devices as one unit?
Ideally I'd like project instructions, tho I understand it would probably be theoretical instructions bc I dont think this has rly been done.

And would my suggested approach for the receiving end even work since the dongle's design isn't an on/off circuit?

Comment: There is a MIDI controller dedicated to sustain - perhaps you can make it easy on yourself by looking for wireless MIDI systems

Comment: Sounds like a nice project, but practically, why would one use a wireless pedal in preference to a wired one, especially since a dongle would have to be plugged in, in place of a jack. And with a more sophisticated full/half pedal system, found on a lot of kb'ds, that's another problem to solve?

Comment: Well, I personally would only use it as a mobile accessory. I travel a good bit and like the idea of being able to use my midi setup without having to deal with cables as much, and could simply pull the pedal out of a backpack, flip a switch, and set it down. I don't use use pedals for anything more than basic sustain so that's not a concern for me.

Answer (score 2):

This can probably be done yourself, it depends a bit your experience with electronics/embedded programing. Here is an idea, there a multiple way of doing it.

There are basically three things this device should do:

- sense the state of the pedal (device #1)
- transmit it to the other dongle
- send it to the keyboard (device #2)

These can all be done for instance with cheap hardware like Arduino, I'll consider the case where you have a boolean sustain pedal (on/off), which typically are connected via a *mono* jack but this should be easily adaptable to an analog one.

### Device #1 (plugged into the pedal)

Here, a simple Arduino connected to a Jack (sleeve to ground, tip to a digital pin set as input pullup) would be completely enough for a start. One problem I see there is that this will need to be powered somehow. If you initial goal was to get rid of cables it might be worth moving to batteries…

### Transmitting

That's a bit more challenging but there are a lot of options to transmit information between two such devices like bluetooth (probably the easiest but would be a bit concerned with latency), RF (probably better on that, might be subjected to interference)… Whatever protocol you choose, you'll need a transmitter (on device #1) and a receiver (on device #2).

### Device #2 (plugged into the keyboard)

This should also be straightforward: a MCU, connected to a Jack (sleeve to ground, tip to an output pin) and switching between high-impedance state of this last pin and output to ground. Not completely sure how fast such a transition is but I doubt it is very slow. Of course, this transition would be triggered by information received on the receiver (whatever protocol you are using).

This is not a complete solution, merely a guide as nothing is implemented but sounds like a fun first project if you want to dive a bit into electronics!

Answer (score 0):

One that is already shipping ([launched at NAMM 2023](https://www.musicradar.com/news/blackbt-susex-pedal)) is [Black BT's SusEx](https://blackbt.com/) costing USD $149.99, that functions as both sustain and expression pedal.

One with less functionality and possibly cheaper is NuMotion's [Wireless Sustain Pedal](https://nu-motion.com/?page_id=29) that seems to be still in development (as of this writing).  They are known for their [wireless curvy keyboard](https://nu-motion.com/?page_id=1509).